# Xcode App crashing error "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, crash

I'm trying to use Firebase to my app and the app keeps crashing.

If I don't implement `FIRApp.configure()` the app runs fine as soon as I use it the app tends to crash.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Also with this error message

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: This is the end of the error message. Scroll up in the debug area to see the beginning of the message, which will give the cause of the error. Without that information it's difficult to say why the app is crashing. If I had to guess, I'd say it is not finding the GoogleServices-Info.JSON file.

Comment: its saying could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project which one is in my project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a GoogleServices-Info.plist file visible in your project, then make sure it's selected as a target.
[image: Xcode]